# How can I simplify my 1st order partial differential equation to fit a second order form?

Tags: derivatives, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

I'm having some difficulties with expressing PDEs in different ways. I'll explain my goals and the steps I have taken so far.

Here's the equation I would LIKE to get:

$$
EI\frac{∂^4w}{∂x^4} + ρA\frac{∂^2w}{∂t^2} = 0
$$

However, my equation is:

$$
\frac{∂w}{∂t} = 0.002w + 0.002\frac{∂w}{∂x} - 0.001\frac{∂^2w}{∂x^2}
$$

Clearly, they are very different, but I would at least like to get it in terms of $\frac{∂^2w}{∂t^2}$ not $\frac{∂w}{∂t}$. Please let me know how to go about expressing this and what assumptions might have to be made. In this case we can assume $t=0$ and $x=0$ initially at least.

So far, I multiplied both sides by $\frac{∂}{∂t}$ and this is what I've done so far:

$$\frac{∂^2w}{∂t^2} = \frac{∂w}{∂t}[0.002w + 0.002\frac{∂w}{∂x} - 0.001\frac{∂^2w}{∂x^2}]$$

$$\frac{∂^2w}{∂t^2} = 0.002\frac{∂w}{∂t} + 0.002\frac{∂w}{∂x∂t} - 0.001\frac{∂^2w}{∂x^2∂t}$$

At this point, I'm not sure how to get "rid" of the $∂t$ partial derivative terms on the right-hand-side. I feel like I'm missing some properties of PDE mathematics, specifically for PDEs involving multiple different partial derivatives as I have $∂t$ and $∂x$ terms

Comment: There is a lot wrong with your post. First, use \partial to get the partial derivative symbol $\partial$. Second, multiplying the equation by $\partial_{t} w$ doesn't give $\partial_{t}^{2} w$ on the left hand side of your equation as you have written, it gives $(\partial_{t} w)^{2}$, nor does $w \partial_{t} w = \partial_{t} w$, nor $\partial_{t} w \partial_{x} w = \partial_{x, t} w$ etc.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say I multiplied by $\frac{d}{dt}$ I'm still getting used to the mathematical formatting here so my bad on that. Still since I am using $\frac{d}{dt}$ I don't think using \partial really helps me express my point as well

Comment: I believe $\frac{∂}{∂t} * \frac{∂w}{∂t}$ should result in $\frac{∂^2w}{∂t^2}$ and that is what I'm basing my simplification off of